# How to get rid of UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning in Node Mongo Express Application

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, ecmascript-6, async-await

**Greetings!**

I have a Node-Express endpoint that calls addAdminController.js (Attached Below) to create a new admin.

Everything works well from functionality point of view. However, ***When you check if user already exists using mongoose FindOne method, it leaves a warning on the console***. This however, does not stop the function from running and I'm successfully returning "Email Already in Use" as json object in Postman.

I want to know why i'm seeing this error and what am I doing wrong with Promise Handling. Your help is much appreciated.

**addAdminController.js**

```
const adminsModel = require("../../../../models/admins");
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");

exports.addAdminController = async (req, res, next) => {
    const { name, email, password, role, image, status } = req.body;

    //check if user already exists
    try {
        adminsModel
            .findOne({ email }, (err, admin) => {
                if (admin) {
                    res.status(400).json("Email Already in use");
                    return;
                }
            })
            .exec();
    } catch (error) {
        return res.status(500).json("Something Went Wrong");
    }

    //Encrypt Password using Bcrypt
    const saltRounds = 12;
    const hashPass = bcrypt.hashSync(password, saltRounds);

    //Create New Model with Hashed Password
    const newAdmin = new adminsModel({
        name: name,
        email: email,
        password: hashPass,
        role: role,
        image: image,
        status: status,
    });

    // Save new admin user.
    try {
        await newAdmin.save();
        res.json(newAdmin);
        return;
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).json("There was an error creating admin user");
    }
};
```

**Console Warning**

```
node:18700) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:533:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (F:07_Developrs\Github\APIv2\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:771:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (F:07_Developrs\Github\APIv2\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:170:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (F:\07_Developrs\Github\APIv2\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:267:15)
    at exports.addAdminController (F:\07_Developrs\Github\APIv2\routes\api\admins\addAdmin\addAdmin.controller.js:37:19)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:18700) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:18700) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn't be using callback version of `findOne` function because code below `findOne` function call will execute before the callback of `findOne` executes.

As code below the `findOne` function call depends on whether user already exists or not, `await` the result of `adminsModel.findOne(...)` and check `findOne` function returned a user or not.

Secondly, wrap `findOne` function call with `try-catch` block to handle rejected promise.

```
try {
     const user = await adminsModel.findOne({ email });
     
     if (user) {
        return res.status(400).json("Email Already in use");
     }
     
     // code to run if user doesn't exists

} catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).json("Something Went Wrong");
}
```

Comment: Hi, I tried but same error again. I updated the above code to show findOne in try-catch.